# Terminar un ciclo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, condiciones

**Hola amigos estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y tenia la duda como terminar el ciclo por así decirlo, tengo que resolver el siguiente problema;**

**Ejercicio**
Max Power tiene hambre.
Si la hora del día está en el rango de 8am a 11am el comprará
un café.
Si la hora del día está en el rango de 12am a 13pm y la
temperatura ambiente se encuentre entre 20° – 25° el
comprará un helado.
Si la hora del día está en el rango de 14pm a 16pm o 20pm a
22pm, comerá un sándwich.
Si la hora es exactamente las 00, no comerá nada y se irá a
dormir.
Diseñe una programa que evalué e imprima la acción que
tomará Max Power.
Discuta con sus compañeros qué variables deberán ser
tomadas en cuenta para resolver este problema y abarcar
todos los casos posibles.
Utilice prompt para guardar los valores en las variables
necesarias.

**Apliqué el siguiente codigo;**

```
var hora        = prompt("¿Que hora del día es?");
    var temperatura = prompt("¿Que temperatura hay?");

    if(hora >= 8 && hora <= 11){
        console.log("Debes comprar un café");
    }
    if(hora >= 12 && hora <= 13 && temperatura >= 20 && temperatura <= 25){
        console.log("Debes comprar un helado");
    }
    if(hora >= 14 && hora <= 16 || hora >= 20 && hora <= 22){
        console.log("Debes comer un sándwich");
    }
    if(hora === 00){
        console.log("No debes comer nada y debes irte a dormir");
    }
```

**Mí pregunta es la siguiente pasa que se supone que si la hora es de 8 a 11 no debería preguntar la variable de arriba de temperatura, me preguntaba como hacer para que al recibir la hora de 8 a 11 el ciclo o la consulta se termine ya que es una hora en la cual no necesito saber la temperatura a diferencia de las demás horas del día.**

Comment: Pues si asumieramos que estamos dentro de un ciclo el cual no veo por ninguna parte entonces se usa la palabra reservada `break` para frenarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hace falta usar "else"

Por el momento tu solo tienes varios "if" que determinan las condiciones de hora y temperatura, pero el problema es que todos tus if están siendo evaluados y solo deberías evaluar uno a la vez, para evaluar solo una condición puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
if(hora >= 8 && hora <= 11){
    console.log("Debes comprar un café");
}
else if(hora >= 12 && hora <= 13 && temperatura >= 20 && temperatura <= 25){
    console.log("Debes comprar un helado");
}
```

Otra opción es utilizar un "switch case" y evaluar el rango de horas en cada caso, mira le siguiente ejemplo para que te des una idea de como podrías evaluar las horas del día al ingresar un valor para "x"

```
switch (true) {
case (x < 5):
    alert("menor a 5");
    break;
case (x < 9):
    alert("entre 5 y 8");
    break;
case (x < 12):
    alert("entre 9 y 11");
    break;
default:
    alert("ninguno");
    break;
}
```

De esta forma al evaluar una única condición podrás resolver tu problema facilmente

Saludos

Comment: La mejor respuesta sin duda que pude haber recibido muchísimas gracias estimado por tomarse el tiempo de ayudar.

Comment: Por nada, si te sirvió por favor acepta la respuesta para cerrar el post

Answer (score 0):

Apenas estoy aprendiendo un poco pero según vi, se puede debe diferenciar entre bucles (y usar el "break;" y un recorrido recursivo (usar el "return;"

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).